# How to implement Calling a function to automatically call another function in javascript

Tags: javascript

All methods inside a class a will call a method b,How to call `c()` or `d()` automatically calls `b()` without writing `b()` in `c()` or `d()`

```js
class a {
  b() {}
  c() {
    b();
    console.log("123")
  }
  d() {
    b();
    console.log("123")
  }
}
```

Comment: What you need. Please explain it clearly

Comment: what is the purpose of doing that?

Comment: It is very troublesome to write b() in each method.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by returning a [`proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) from `a`'s constructor that intercepts name lookups and tests whether they are functions. If they are, call `b` (unless you actually called `b`):

```js
class a {
    constructor(){
        const handler = {
            get(target, propKey, receiver) {
                const targetValue = Reflect.get(target, propKey, receiver);
                
                if (typeof targetValue === 'function') {                     
                    return function (...args) {
                        // don't recursively call b
                        if (propKey !=='b') target.b()
                        return targetValue.apply(this, args); // call original function
                    }
                } else {
                    return targetValue;
                }
            }
        };
        return new Proxy(this, handler);           
    }
    b(){
        console.log('b called')
    }
    c(arg){
     console.log("c called with ", arg)
    }
    d(){
     console.log("d called")
    }
 }
 


 let instance = new a
 
 instance.c("hello")
 instance.d() 
 instance.b()  // only called once  

 // still works for methods set after the fact:
 a.prototype.g = function(){
     console.log("g called")
 }

 instance.g()  // still calls b
```

Answer (score 1):

You could traverse the `.prototype` property of `a`, and overwrite each method with one that first calls `b`.

```js
class a {
  b() { console.log("called b") }
  c() {
    console.log("called c")
  }
  d() {
    console.log("called d")
  }
}
for (const n of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a.prototype)) {
  const f = a.prototype[n];
  if (typeof f === "function" && n !== "b") {
    a.prototype[n] = function(...args) {
      this.b();
      return f.apply(this, args);
    }
  }
}

var aa = new a();
aa.c();
aa.d();
```